# Whitelabel Error Page, This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpFTo.jpg)This is my Controller, I'm accessing with port localhost:8080 it is returning white label error. What may be the  reason?

```
@RestController 
public class EmployeeController {

@GetMapping("/")    
public String hello() {         
return "service is up and running";     
}
```

Comment: can you share your project structure?

Comment: I've updated the image of my project structure!

Answer (score 6):

The issue is related to your project structure, by default Spring Boot will scan the components below your main application class.

In your case your main is located at package `com.navajna.aaa`, and your controller is located at package `com.navajna.controller`.

I would recommend you to keep your controller in a new package below the `com.navajna.aaa` package, like `com.navajna.aaa.controller` as per structure mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code).

If you really want to use the `com.navajna.controller` package, you may need to add the `@ComponentScan("com.navajna.controller")`.Details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation).

Comment: Yes! my main class is present in com.navajna.aaa, I've changed the name of the package to com.navajna and controller is below the main package as com.navajna.controller